# Server 2008 R2 Exact Firewall Rule For RDP

Tags: firewall, rdp

I have a server 2008 r2 and have changed the RDP port and a few other things. Is there a way to lock down the changed port to only work on the rdp service. I set incoming rule to system/services but when i tried setting for various rdp services it kickd me out. Simply I wanted the changed port to work on RDP only so nothing else can be used on it.

EDIT

Under my rule, Programs and Services > Services > Apply to this service. Before I tried selecting one but it would let me know. I want my allow rule to only work for a single service.

Comment: So you're saying that you need to prevent other services from listening on the port that RDP is listening on?  Just having the RDP service running accomplishes that.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot run multiple services on the same port, so as long as Remote Desktop (Terminal) Services is running, the nonstandard port is protected. This doesn't mean that you can't **configure** multiple services to run on the same port, however.

You can set two services set to run on port 443 (such as IIS and RDS) and to start at boot. By doing so, you create a race condition where either service could grab the port, and it's impossible to know which would win (all else equal). But you're a  [professional sysadmin](https://serverfault.com/faq#questions), so you know what's running on which port, right? And you can correct the configuration so that only one service is on each port, right?

Comment: Iain, Joel and Shane,
Thank you. As said have checked net stat and pid links to RDP. Only one mentioned so ok now. Have left as system/services and 3 ips only.
Cheers